# ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [__tested_artifact__::CordovaLib]

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating a cordova android project first time.upto build project everythings goes okey.after building the project, when I try to open  in the Android IDE, Android Studio,
I'm getting this error.

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be
>   smaller than version 19 declared in library
>   [**tested_artifact**::CordovaLib]
>   E:\projects\cordova\hello1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 1     Suggestion: use
>   a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,      or increase this
>   project's minSdk version to at least 19,      or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to
>   runtime failures)

here is setup information
[image]
[image]

I tried adding
preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"
In Config.xml (Project directory).
It didn't work.

Please help me fixing this.
Thanks,

Comment: I am also getting this error what version of android studio are you running and have you found a fix for this issue?

Comment: I'm using Android 3.4.Still couldn't find a fix for the issue..

Comment: did you find a fix ?

Comment: @  Lilian Bideau, no.I couldn't find a solution.If I make a any changes in android studio IDE to fix the issue, then i get errors when building the project next time in cordova environment.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
```

inside `android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml` helped to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue when building my app with Ionic. I solved it by making changes to ***gradle.properties(Project Properties)*** file. Change the ***cdvMinSdkVersion*** to the min targeted version which in my case was 22 then click on sync project. After build or run the project.

```
cdvMinSdkVersion=22
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue when building my app with Ionic. I solved it by making changes to gradle.properties(Project Properties) file. Change the cdvMinSdkVersion to the min targeted version which in my case was 22 then click on sync project. After build or run the project.

cdvMinSdkVersion=22

This worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on Cordova, But works on Android apps development. The issue you described is because you are using library that has minSdkVersion 19. And you cannot use lower then that in your project. Change minSdkVersion in /platforms/android/app/build.gradle file.
As you need to change apps minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Change the cdvMinSdkVersion in gradle.properties