# Capacitor 3 and Ionic 6 Android build hitting "uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:capacitor-app]"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm quite stuck here despite having found a few quite similar Stack Overflow questions.

My specific case is trying to get an app to build on Android which I recently updated to Ionic 6 and most notably added Capacitor – while still using Cordova for a couple of plugins, but no longer for builds.

The work in progress is public on [this branch](https://github.com/webful-ltd/passwordmaker/tree/ionic-6).

The build error I get is:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:capacitor-app] /Users/noel/files/Dev/PasswordMaker/node_modules/@capacitor/app/android/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 1
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.capacitorjs.plugins.app" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

As you can see, I've already:

- [ensured `variables.gradle` has a sensible `minSdkVersion` value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68331750/2803757) – Capacitor 3 had already done this on setup I think
- [removed the top level SDK version manifest bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57840462/2803757) – I know this answer's about Cordova, but I don't seem to have a manifest at that path despite having some Cordova plugins still
- I temporarily tried [this plugin version override option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30208480/2803757), but this still didn't build and I think would just get it to try and revert the plugin back to API v1 which is not what I want

I also tried some hail mary options like hard-coding a `uses-sdk` minimum version in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of *every* single module that shows up in Android Studio, but to no avail.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Ideally I just want to build the project with minimum SDK 21, and target 30, without it falling over! The iOS build seems to be working fine and `npx cap doctor` reports no issues.

```
npx cap doctor
   Capacitor Doctor   

Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/core: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/android: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/ios: 3.3.3

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/android: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/ios: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/cli: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/core: 3.3.3

[success] iOS looking great! 
[success] Android looking great!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Solution**

In Android Studio, Select `File > Project Structure`.

[image]

In that window, on the left side, select the `app` module.
Once selected, click on the `Flavors` tab on the top of the window pane.
Set your minimum SDK version to 21.

[image]

**Explanation**: As Android updates to new versions, tools that developers use for Android change (& update or deprecate). Because of this, you cannot use *new tools* on an *old version*. Version `1` is the very first Android SDK (and we definitely don't want to be using that!). Capacitor requires the SDK be at least version `21`.

**Second Solution**

If that doesn't work, we can always try rebuilding the android app all together. (Note: By doing this, you will lose any custom changes in the AndroidManifest.xml, a custom app icon, etc. If you haven't touched any of these things, then great!).

1. Delete `android` folder from the Ionic Project's root folder.
2. run command `ionic capacitor add android`
3. run command `ionic capacitor build android`
4. Build & run!

Comment: Thanks! Something had gone odd with the versions for sure as it seemed like it was already interpolating the right min version in the only module 'flavor'. But starting over with a clean `android` got round this particular problem. I'm still not 100% clear on the specific change that broke it but `compileSdkVersion` in the Gradle properties seems to be redundant and possibly implicated.

Comment: @NoelLH Glad you got it working  We've all run into odd environment issues like one; we all hate them!

Comment: Thank you for the Second solution, because couldn't so First Solution.  In Android Studio 2021.1 Patch 2, I don't see any Modules, under
**File | Product Structure..** 
I see modules, a second panel with app and a bunch of capacitor modules (?), 
Default Config lists Target SDK Version: as $targetSdkVersion (30 ... )